# How to cancel query as non-superuser?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm a non-superuser on a PostgreSQL 9.1 database, and I've just created a bad trigger function that won't stop. I can see the process, e.g.:

```
thedb=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE procpid = 45678;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-------------------------------------------------------------------
datid            | 596281
datname          | thedb
procpid          | 45678
usesysid         | 596282
usename          | myuser
application_name | QGIS
client_addr      | 1.2.3.4
client_hostname  |
client_port      | 12345
backend_start    | 2015-04-16 13:45:27.482691+12
xact_start       | 2015-04-16 14:17:34.633156+12
query_start      | 2015-04-16 14:17:34.633665+12
waiting          | f
current_query    | UPDATE ...
```

But I can't stop it:

```
thedb=> SELECT pg_terminate_backend(45678);
ERROR:  must be superuser to signal other server processes
```

Is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either be the superuser *or* logged in as the same user who owns the session you wish to cancel.

So connect as user `myuser` and you'll be able to `pg_cancel_backend`, or, if that doesn't respond, `pg_terminate_backend`.

Comment: Neither command works from my role, with message "must be superuser to signal other server processes". [The docs for 9.1 say you need to be superuser](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html) (however, they are [slightly different for 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-admin.html))

Comment: @MikeT In that case, since you're on an older version, you'd better ask the sysadmin or someone else with superuser access for help, or kill the client-side process that's running the query.

Comment: Yup, it required a sysadmin to fix. The non-superuser approach requires a little known [feature from 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html) that I now have just found.

Comment: @MikeT Huh, I wasn't aware that query cancel on remote disconnect was as new as 9.2. Thanks for the pointer.